# R incorrect y-axis in ggplots geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe with Wikipedia edits, with information about the number of edit for the user (1st edit, 2nd edit and so on), the timestamp when the edit was made, and how many words were added.

In the actual dataset, I have up to 20.000 edits per user and in some edits, they add up to 30.000 words.

However, [here is a downloadable small example](https://ufile.io/39dsc) dataset to exemplify my problem. The header looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to plot the distribution of added words across the Edit Progression and across time. If I use the regular R barplot, i works just like expected:

`barplot(UserFrame3$NoOfAdds,UserFrame3$EditNo)`

[image]

But I want to do it in ggplot for nicer graphics and more customizing options.

If I plot this as a scatterplot, I get the same result:

`ggplot(data = UserFrame3, aes(x = UserFrame3$EditNo, y = UserFrame3$NoOfAdds))  + geom_point(size = 0.1)`

[image]

Same for a linegraph:

`ggplot(data = UserFrame3, aes(x = UserFrame3$EditNo, y = UserFrame3$NoOfAdds)) +geom_line(size = 0.1)`

[image]

**But when I try to plot it as a bargraph in ggplot, I get this result:**

`ggplot(data = UserFrame3, aes(x = UserFrame3$EditNo, y = UserFrame3$NoOfAdds)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")`

[image]

There appear to be a lot more holes on the X-axis and the maximum is nowhere close to where it should be (y = 317).

I suspect that ggplot somehow groups the bars and uses means instead of the actual values despite the "dodge" parameter? How can I avoid this? and how would I go about plotting the time progression as a bargraph aswell without ggplot averaging over multiple edits?

Comment: can you show the data using `dput()` rather providing a link. This example works for me `mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  position = "dodge")`

Comment: that would be a pretty long string, should I just post it here anyways?

Comment: I recommend to reduce the data so far that one can comprehend
the problem but not to overload your question ;)

Comment: In the `aes` you should be using `EditNo` not `UserFrame3$EditNo`

Comment: @Jimbou I think part of the problem is the amount of data because I don't run into similar issues when I tried to replicate it with a smaller dataset. For comprehensieveness though, I will edit my question and include the header of the example dataframe!

Comment: @RichardTelford You are right, specifying the dataframe again is probably redundant but changing it doesn't solve my main problem...

Comment: Which ggplot version do you use?

Comment: @Jimbou I'm using ggplot2_2.2.1

Comment: @JuKo, using `$` is not just redundant, it can cause serious issues, for example with facetting. As far as the question goes, you need a reproducible example _within the question itself_. Not sure why you are setting a `position` argument there.

Comment: @Axeman Okay, good to know! I thought it was just redundant. For reproducibility, there is my code and my dataset but I don't know how to properly included it in the question itself. I considered inlcuding the data with dput() but he output would be pages long. I also tried to reproduce the issue with a subset from my data and other smaller datasets but could not reproduce it so far.

Comment: @JuKo is this solved now?

Answer (score 1):

You should expect more x-axis "holes" using bars as compared with lines. Lines connect the zero values together, bars do not.

I used `geom_col` with your data download, it looks as expected:

```
UserFrame3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(EditNo, NoOfAdds)) + geom_col()
```

[image]